# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll' (CentOS 7)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, quantum-computing, q#

I am trying to get [Microsoft's Quantum Development Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-installconfig?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-vscode) to work on a CentOS 7 machine.  I followed the [instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started-with-dotnet-tutorial) for installing `dotnet`, and the trivial `dotnet` 'Hello World' works. I also installed Visual Studio from `yum` and installed the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit for Visual Studio from the Visual Studio explorer.

After cloning their github repo. I try:

```
dotnet_vm: Teleportation$ cd ~/Quantum/Samples/Teleportation/
dotnet_vm: Teleportation$ scl enable rh-dotnet21 bash
dotnet_vm: Teleportation$ dotnet run
/home/user/Quantum/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.csproj : warning NU1603: Microsoft.Quantum.Canon depends on NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03) but NETStandard.Library 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03 was not found. An approximate best match of NETStandard.Library 2.0.2 was resolved. [/home/user/Quantum/Samples/Teleportation/TeleportationSample.csproj]
/home/user/Quantum/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.csproj : warning NU1603: Microsoft.Quantum.Canon depends on NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03) but NETStandard.Library 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03 was not found. An approximate best match of NETStandard.Library 2.0.2 was resolved.

Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libMicrosoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators.QuantumSimulator.Init()
   at Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators.QuantumSimulator..ctor(Boolean throwOnReleasingQubitsNotInZeroState, Nullable`1 randomNumberGeneratorSeed, Boolean disableBorrowing)
   at Microsoft.Quantum.Examples.Teleportation.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/user/Quantum/Samples/Teleportation/Program.cs:line 13
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579153/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-quantum-simulator-runtime-dll/49619059) looks like the same error.  I tried what I thought was the linux equivalent solution :

```
cp ~/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/runtimes/linux-x64/native/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll ~/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/
```

I still get the same Error.  Also, I do not have the AVX instruction set enabled on my computer (which might be a potential issue?).

E.g.

```
 grep flags /proc/cpuinfo 
flags       : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm nopl pni cx16 hypervisor lahf_lm abm
flags       : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm nopl pni cx16 hypervisor lahf_lm abm
dotnet_vm: Teleportation$
```

I do not have any Windows experience and these do not look like typical Linux libraries (not .so or .a).

QUESTION:
How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following El capi's answer, I looked at the libraries linked to : e.g.

```
dotnet_vm: gcc-5.1.0$ ldd /home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll
/home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll)
/home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll)
/home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/user/.nuget/packages/microsoft.quantum.development.kit/0.2.1809.701-preview/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2f12b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1fb5fee000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1fb5cec000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f1fb5ac6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1fb56f9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1fb656a000)
```

To resolve this versioning issue with regards to GLIBCXX_3.4.21, I installed gcc-5.1.0 (and its dependencies).  Then running the code:

```
dotnet_vm: Teleportation$ dotnet run
/home/user/Quantum/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.csproj : warning NU1603: Microsoft.Quantum.Canon depends on NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03) but NETStandard.Library 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03 was not found. An approximate best match of NETStandard.Library 2.0.2 was resolved. [/home/user/Quantum/Samples/Teleportation/TeleportationSample.csproj]
/home/user/Quantum/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.csproj : warning NU1603: Microsoft.Quantum.Canon depends on NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03) but NETStandard.Library 2.0.2-servicing-25519-03 was not found. An approximate best match of NETStandard.Library 2.0.2 was resolved.
Round 0:    Sent True,  got True.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 1:    Sent False, got False.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 2:    Sent True,  got True.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 3:    Sent False, got False.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 4:    Sent True,  got True.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 5:    Sent False, got False.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 6:    Sent True,  got True.
Teleportation successful!!

Round 7:    Sent False, got False.
Teleportation successful!!



Press Enter to continue...
```

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

The `Microsoft.Quantum.Simulator.Runtime.dll` is a normal Linux library (.so), it's just renamed to make it easier to support cross-platform.

It does look like a similar problem from the one that [you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579153/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-quantum-simulator-runtime-dll/49619059), however you should look into the `Ubuntu` answer: use `ldd` to figure out what the dependencies are and install anything that is missing. As in that post, the problem most probably is that you're missing `libgomp`, but I'm not familiar with CentOS.

Not having AVX enabled will make things slower, specially when dealing with lots of qubits, but you should still be able to run.